# Python - Not printing output in a function

Tags: python, printing, menu

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a code that takes from the user an input of money spent, number of transactions and it gives back the average value that was spent. So far I have this:

```
def compra(conta, valor):
    conta["saldo"] = conta["saldo"] + valor
    conta["transacoes"] = conta["transacoes"] + 1
    conta["media"] = (conta["media"]*(conta["transacoes"]-1)+valor)/conta["transacoes"]

    return(conta)
    
print(f"Os valores de saldo, transações e média são: {conta['saldo']} {conta['transacoes']} {conta['media']}")
    
while True:
    valordacompra = float(input('Digite o valor da compra: '))
```

But I am not sure how to make it show on the screen what the values are after getting the input. If some more information is needed let me know ! Thank you

Comment: You have to call the function and store its return value.

Comment: Of course ! lol, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

money_spent = int(input('How much money was spent?: '))
num_transactions = int(input('How many transactions?: '))

average_value = money_spent / num_transactions

print("The average value is " + str(average_value) + '$')
```

Also keep an eye on exceptions. For example if the user typed in "cat" instead of a number. You can do this by using try ... except

```
import math

while True:
    try:
        money_spent = int(input('How much money was spent?: '))
        num_transactions = int(input('How many transactions?: '))

        average_value = money_spent / num_transactions

        print("The average value is " + str(average_value) + '$')
        
        break
        
    except:
        ValueError
        print('Type in a number')
```

Comment: Thanks man ! That was a very smarter way to do it

Comment: No problem. I also added another code block for exception handling (E.g. if the user typed in "cat" instead of 1234). You can flag this post as the correct answer if you like.

Comment: Ok that was a really nice touch to avoid some bugs, thank you ! I will implement that